# Is there a modifier to change the label color of SwiftUI Picker?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I want to change the label color of `SwiftUI Picker` from blue to black, tried `.foregroundColor(.black)` and `.tint(.black)`, but the color remains blue.

```
@State var privacy = Privacy.open
enum Privacy: String, CaseIterable, Identifiable {
    case open = "Open"
    case closed = "Closed"
    var id: String {
        self.rawValue
    }
}
    
var body: some View {
    Picker("privacy", selection: $privacy) {
        ForEach(Privacy.allCases) { value in
            Text(value.rawValue)
                .tag(value)
        }
    }
    .pickerStyle(.menu)
    .tint(.black)
    .foregroundColor(.black)
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I tried `foregroundStyle` and `accentColor` and only `accentColor` worked. It does have a future deprecation warning, but you should be able to use it for now.

```
.accentColor(.orange)
```

Comment: This works for me, but only if I explicitly define '.pickerStyle(.menu)'

Answer (score 9):

As the other user has mentioned, `.accentColor(.orange)` works, but has a depreciation warning.

Using `.tint(.orange)` does not have this warning and will color the picker text.

Answer (score 1):

neither `tint` or `accentColor` worked for me. I created a view modifier in which I updated the `setTitleTextAttributes` values for `.foregroundColor`.

```
struct SegmentPickerModifier: ViewModifier {

init() {
    let colorAppearance = UISegmentedControl.appearance()
    colorAppearance.backgroundColor = .red
    colorAppearance.selectedSegmentTintColor = .blue
    colorAppearance.tintColor = .green
    colorAppearance.setTitleTextAttributes([.foregroundColor : UIColor.white], for: .normal)
    colorAppearance.setDividerImage(
        UIImage(),
        forLeftSegmentState: .normal,
        rightSegmentState: .normal,
        barMetrics: .default
    )

}

func body(content: Content) -> some View {
    content
}
}
```

Comment: This worked well for the `.segmented` style but not for others.